# Hadoop Pig ordered results; find order position?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to sort my pig results, and then be able to determine where certain items are in my ordered results.  Example:

```
mydata = LOAD 'mydata.txt' AS (label:chararray, rank_score:float);
ranked_data = ORDER mydata BY rank_score DESC;
ranked_positions = FOREACH ranked_data GENERATE label, AUTO_INCREMENT_ID;
results = FILTER ranked_data BY label = 'item1' OR label='item2';
DUMP results;
```

`AUTO_INCREMENT_ID` would auto-increment in my perfect world.  Given how mappers/reducers are independent from each other, I'm guessing Pig/Hadoop may not support this.  If not, can you think of another way to generate my end result?

Example input:

```
item1       34.33
item2       48.39
item3       93.3
```

Desired output:

```
item1       3
item2       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set parallelism of ORDER to 1, you can just do auto-increment yourself in a udf; of course, that would have the potentially undesired effect of only using 1 reducer to do your sorting.

(Also, I am not sure how you got your example output -- the input seems to be already ordered, so item1 should have id 1 and item 2 should have id 2, right? did you mean to order by rank_score *desc*?)

Comment: Thanks, I did mean to order descending, so I updated my post accordingly.  I think you're right that the one reducer route is the only way to go.  Would the syntax be: `ranked_data = ORDER mydata BY rank_score DESC PARALLEL 1;` ?